Unknown field postDetail for include statement on model Post. Available options are marked with?

I’m encountering an issue with a Prisma query where I’m trying to include related models in the findUnique method. My Prisma schema defines a relation called PostDetail, but Prisma Client throws a validation error indicating that PostDetail is an unknown field.
Here’s the relevant part of my Prisma schema:
model Post {
  id         String      @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title      String
  price      Int
  images     String[]
  address    String
  city       String
  bedroom    Int
  bathroom   Int
  latitude   String
  longitude  String
  type       Type
  property   Property
  createdAt  DateTime    @default(now())
  user       User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId     String      @db.ObjectId
  PostDetail PostDetail?
  SavedPost  SavedPost[]
}

In my code, I’m trying to include the PostDetail relation:
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import prisma from './prisma'; 
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export const getPost = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const id = req.params.id; 

  try {
    const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        PostDetail: true,
        user: {
          select: {
            username: true,
            avatar: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Post not found" });
    }

    const token = req.cookies?.token;

    if (token) {
      try {
        const payload: any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY as string);
        const saved = await prisma.savedPost.findUnique({
          where: {
            userId_postId: {
              postId: id,
              userId: payload.id,
            },
          },
        });

        return res.status(200).json({ ...post, isSaved: Boolean(saved) });
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
      }
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ ...post, isSaved: false });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to get post" });
  }
};

Error Message:
PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.post.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: "66accf0392161e63dcbdd443"
  },
  include: {
    PostDetail: true,
    ~~~~~~~~~~
    user: {
      select: {
        username: true,
        avatar: true
      }
    },
    ?   PostDetail?: true,
    ?   SavedPost?: true
  }
}

Unknown field `PostDetail` for include statement on model `Post`. Available options are marked with ?.

What I’ve Tried:

Verified the model name in schema.prisma matches the include statement.
Regenerated Prisma Client with npx prisma generate.
Checked the Prisma documentation and Studio for correct model names and relations.

